# STS freeze during build workspace on startup

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I am running Spring STS 3.4.0 on Mac OS 10.8 with Tomcat 7, maven 3.1.1 installed, but almost everytime I start STS, try to open any project it freezes while building workspace at exactly 42%. By checking the log file, I found the following:

Can someone please tell me what is wrong and how I can possibly fix this problem?

Note: I don't have any firewall

Thanks

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2014-02-09 16:04:41.657
>   !MESSAGE Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:jar:2.9
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2014-02-09 16:04:41.695
>   !MESSAGE Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1: Plugin
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 or one of its dependencies
>   could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2014-02-09 16:04:42.178
>   !MESSAGE Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:jar:2.9
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2014-02-09 16:04:42.194
>   !MESSAGE Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1: Plugin
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1 or one of its dependencies
>   could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.1
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2014-02-09 16:04:44.447
>   !MESSAGE Using platform encoding (US-ASCII actually) to copy filtered
>   resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2014-02-09 16:04:44.525
>   !MESSAGE Using platform encoding (US-ASCII actually) to copy filtered
>   resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! !SESSION 2014-02-09
>   16:21:47.448 -----------------------------------------------
>   eclipse.buildId=3.4.0.201310051614-RELEASE-e43 java.version=1.7.0_45
>   java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=macosx,
>   ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.springsource.sts.ide -keyring /Users/mkm/.eclipse_keyring
>   -showlocation Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide -keyring
>   /Users/mkm/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-02-09 16:22:07.157 !MESSAGE
>   Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal
>   accelerator operation. !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-02-09
>   16:22:07.157 !MESSAGE A conflict occurred for COMMAND+SHIFT+F10:
>   Binding(COMMAND+SHIFT+F10,
>     ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.jboss.tools.common.ui.RegisterAsService,Register
>   As Service,       Adds class name to META-INF/services/%serviceType% file
>   after service type is selected in the dialog from types extended and
>   implemented by the class.,
>         Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.file,File,null,true),
>         org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@241a8926,
>         ,,true),null),  org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
>     org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system) Binding(COMMAND+SHIFT+F10,
>     ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.window.showSystemMenu,Show
>   System Menu,      Show the system menu,
>         Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.window,Window,null,true),
>         org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@4a22304e,
>         ,,true),null),  org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
>     org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,cocoa,system)

Comment: I face the same problem sometime but couldn't find a resolution, if you found any please share it here..